# How to write a function so that code is omitted when arguments are undefined?

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

I'm writing automated test cases using Javascript to perform GUI actions. I'm writing a function to handle some basic "initialization" operations on the software under test but I wanted to have the option to not necessarily put every argument into the parameters.

So I had a function that basically did this:

```
function initializeApp(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
{
    action1(arg1);
    action2(arg2);
    action3(arg3);
    action4(arg4);
}
```

But lets say that I didn't want to perform action 4, right now the code contained inside the "action4" block would not be able to handle there not being input for arg4 and would crash. So the hamfisted way I thought about getting around this issue was to create a bunch of `if` and `else if` statements that would essentially skip over different code blocks if that argument was undefined. Here's an example:

```
function testIES(configFile, recordFile, overwrite, scriptFile)
{
    if (arg1 == undefined)
    {
        action2(arg2);
        action3(arg3);
        action4(arg4);
    } else if (arg2 == undefined)
    {
        action1(arg1);
        action3(arg3);
        action4(arg4);
    } else if (arg3 == undefined)
    {
        action1(arg1);
        action2(arg2);
        action4(arg4);
    } else if (arg4 == undefined)
    {
        action1(arg1);
        action2(arg2);
        action3(arg3);
    }
}
```

However, this approach has an obvious flaw in that I'd need to come up with every combination of "actions" if I wanted to be able to leave out more than 1 argument. It would also not be very user friendly if anyone else wanted to do it because they'd have to know not to leave out more than one argument. So is my best option simply coming up with all the different combinations? Or is there a better way? Surely there's a better way.

Comment: You should look into arguments object  of function to handle dynamic arguments passed to function. Let me know if you understood it or not.

Comment: How about the opposite condition…? *If arg1 is defined, execute action1. If arg2 is defined, execute action2…* That’s one condition per argument and action.

Comment: @deceze I was getting ready to write a comment explaining why that wouldn't work. As I was writing it out, I realized that I think you're right... lol I'm going to try that.

Comment: @deceze The only the that doesn't work with that one is if I want to be able to be clever and give myself the ability to leave arg1 undefined but define 2-4. I mean, its not that big of a deal, I can just set it to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

this allows undefined and falsey's to be passed:

```
function initializeApp(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
{
   var len = arguments.length;
    if(len>0)action1(arg1);
    if(len>1)action2(arg2);
    if(len>2)action3(arg3);
    if(len>3)action4(arg4);
}
```

If you will never pass a false-like value (0, null, `false`, etc), you can use a simpler form like

`if(arg1) action1(arg1);`

Answer (score 0):

You could take the arguments and an array of functions for each argument and iterate and check it the parameter is set, then call the function at the same index.

```
function testIES(...args) {
    [action1, action2, action3, action4].forEach((fn, i) {
        if (args[i] === undefined) return;
        fn(args[i]);
    });
}
```

Comment: what if the 3rd of 4 arguments is _supposed_ to be `undefined`? (that can happen)

Comment: the third parameter is not used. but the question is a bit unclear, because it allows only one missing parameter or so ...?

Comment: if, i pass `(true, 4, undefined, "success")` for example, it seems that the third action would not be called in the above code.

Comment: then it takes `true`, `4` and `'success'`. undefined is here no value, but it could be replaced with a symbol for `none`, like an über `undefined`.

Comment: fair enough, i don't want to nit pick edges. a fake `undefined` _could_ require downstream refactoring though...